# How can I have a cell flash green or red dpending on whether the updated value is higher, or lower? - In Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am running an excel spreadsheet. Some of the values are being fed in from an external source. In this case, it is the price of crude oil.

The cell is updating in real time.

I would like to have the cell flash red or green as the price moves higher or lower?

Or some arrows next to it pointing up or down?

Either is fine!

How about a macro, or some clever formatting??

Whats the solution wizards?

Answer (score 2):

Excel has always had conditional formatting that does exactly this. Each newer version adds nicer tools. You can combine formatting rules to add both arrow icons and background colors (conditionally red/green etc). Real time changes are updated automatically. Here's an example using Excel 2013:
[image: Sample Excel conditional formatting.]

Comment: Thank you but the values are not in a list, it is one cell that is continuously updating, there fore there is no other cell to compare values, it needs to be compared against its previous value rather than another cell.

Comment: If your RTD formula doesn't store the last value, you'll need to do that yourself - perhaps in a hidden adjacent cell, and then create a conditional formatting rule to compare the two cells. You can update your question to reflect that you aren't interested in formatting but how to save the last value from RTD() if that's the real question.

Answer (score 0):

If you get old and new price from external source, you can use [Conditional Formatting](http://www.contextures.com/xlCondFormat01.html) to change background color of selected cells.
For example, if old price is bigger than the new one, it shows green, and if the price raises, it changes to red.

Comment: Thank you but the values are not in a list, it is one cell that is continuously updating, there fore there is no other cell to compare values, it needs to be compared against its previous value rather than another cell.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy current values to an other place/sheet and then update the values. After that you can compare and format with "Conditional Formatting", because then you have "old" and new prices.